# Moving client data from one database to a new one

Tags: sql-server

Our application architecture allows us to host multiple clients in a single database, and also host multiple databases.  This allows us to scale out by distributing clients across multiple databases.  For example, 20 clients can be in database A, and another 15 could be in database B.  We use a ClientID field in almost every table to partition client data.  All our table's primary keys are INT identity TableID fields.

I'm looking for a tool/script that would help me extract client data from one database, and move it to a brand new database (so the PKs can stay the same).  I'm hoping this exists already so we don't have to build our own.  Pretty flexible in how this could work, but ideally it just generates a large .sql file with all the necessary INSERTS in the right order to move the data, and another sql file with all the necessary DELETES to erase the data from the source.

If it makes any difference we are on SQL Server 2008.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have standard or enterprise, you do have SSIS. Although it may not qualify as a "tool", it is fairly easy to implement in this scenario.

Comment: Ok, will check out SSIS to see what it can do.  Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

I can recomend redgate [SQL DataCompare](http://www.red-gate.com/products/SQL_Data_Compare/index.htm) for this, we use it for syncing data, and use their [SQL Compare](http://www.red-gate.com/products/SQL_Compare/index_v2.htm) to sync the database schema.

Both tools can either output sql, you can execute yourself, or the tools can execute the sql scripts themself.

They have a command line version of the tools to, so you could use them in an deployment script, tho i haven't tried this.

They both work really well, and are no doubt worth the price.

Comment: AndreasN, thanks for the recommendation.  Just to be clear though, I'm not doing any comparison or synchronizing.  What I'd like to do is move a batch of related data based on ClientID from one database to a new one.  Does this tool do that?

Comment: Can't you do this with the tools inside SQL-Server? SSIS etc.

Comment: Maybe.  Not very familiar with SSIS.  I guess I'll check that out.

Answer (score 0):

Not the answer you may be looking for, but you should consider using a GUID as a key.  This will ensure that you have some type of unique identifier for your all records and that you can avoid collisions with identity keys / integer based indexes.  It would add another degree of traceability should something go wrong when you migrate between databases.

SplendidCRM uses this technique when importing data from other DB systems.

---

Update:

My assumption was that the operation of transferring data between databases was not that frequent and that you needed database architecture for that task.  I would use the GUID as lookup key specifically validation for the transfer of data, but I would NOT use that as a primary key for joins for standard operations like URL's.  Although unique across databases, the trade-off is that GUIDs are slow.

In other words, the GUIDS would in addition to your existing primary keys now, and act as a means of validation for you should something go wrong.  If you need ClientID in Database A to retain the same value in Database B then an identity column as that identifier will be an issue.  You may have to create another identifier that is not "auto-generated".  This could something other than the GUID, but my instinct is that integers alone will not be enough.  Maybe you can create a columns that is a hash of the identity key, customer name and database name, or more simply, just concatenate those columns into a varchar column.

Comment: David, are there performance trade-offs if you use GUID keys and do a lot of joins?  Also, one reason we did not go this route is we thought it would make a mess of our application URLs when referring to a resource.